Next-UI autocomplete options list overflows screen if too big
screenshot of pageI am currently working on an UI with NEXT.js and NEXT-UI. My problem is that i want to use Autocomplete compontent with pretty long texts for options. The problem is that the popover (the list of options) overflows the screen to the right.
By default it is so that the dropdown cant be bigger that the input field. In order to get around that i added the tailwind class "w-fit"
<Autocomplete scrollShadowProps={{isEnabled: false}} isLoading={isLoading} size="sm" fullWidth label="Signo" className="flex-1 min-w-32" popoverProps={{ className: "w-fit" }}>
   {standardtext?.schluessel.map(schluessel => <AutocompleteItem startContent={schluessel.schluessel} title={schluessel.langtext} key={schluessel.schluessel} textValue={schluessel.schluessel}></AutocompleteItem>) || <AutocompleteItem key={"nothing"}></AutocompleteItem>}
 </Autocomplete>

but now the problem is that i overflows as shown on top
My goal is that the options list places itsslef dynamically like the the one in Dropdown Component from Next Ui

So i found the answer to my problem by chance while trying to force the element into postion with javascript....
You just have to pass a HTMLDivElement to the popoverProps on the Autocomplete component
<Autocomplete popoverProps={{ className: "w-fit", ref: popoverRef}}>
To get the ref i used a React hook createRef at the top of my function:
const popoverRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
